# How can I get my microphone to work in a virtualbox windows xp guest?

Tags: virtualbox

I have been trying to get this to work for several days. I have googled until I can't google anymore.....

I have Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit with Virtualbox Ver. 3.2.8 installed. I have a windows xp pro guest. I am running Rosettas stone in the guest. Everything works great except the mic.

The guest audio is:

Host Driver:PulseAudio
Controller:ICH AC97

This works well in Lucid. In XP it's as if the os doesn't know how to use the mic. I see it in the xp sound app. It doesn't work but it's listed as intel integrated sudio. When I run sound recorder , I click on record and the bar/slider that indicates time recording doesn't move.

Are there any settings in VB that I need to modify to get this to work?

I tried getting rosetta stone to work in wine but had no luck.

Comment: why is this considered too localized?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:
Go left click on sound indicator on Ubuntu and chose Sound Preferences
In the Input tab on conector chose your Mic (for me work Microphone 2)
Then go to System > Administration > User and Groups
Click on Manage Groups, scoll down on vboxusers select hem with 1 left click an then click on Properties and check your user name box and click OK
Open VirtualBox, turn on your XP Guest, right click on sound icon (in your XP Guest), chose Open Volume Control.
In the windows that apear, go to Options and click on Properties
Scroll down and check Microphone box. and then click OK

Or look to this Screencast: http://screenr.com/qIG

For my works fine but because i use screenr.com that blow my demonstration :D

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `/etc/group/vboxusers` includes your user name. Run this in terminal and look for the `vboxusers` entry

```
$ grep vboxusers /etc/group
vboxusers:x:111:alice,bill
```

If your user name isn't in there then add it:

```
sudo gpasswd -a bill vboxusers
```

Replace `bill` with your username.