# Virtualbox - how to route sound from Ubuntu host to Windows guest?

Tags: networking, sound, windows, virtualbox, pulseaudio

Is it possible to route my audio output from my Ubuntu Host to my Windows 7 Guest in Viurtualbox? So it appears as a line input? 
I'm thinking of connecting windows to my PulseAudio server, but as far as I know, there is no usable implementation for this.

Does anybody here have experience with this topic?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried using JACK?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not impossible, others report having the microphone working in their windows guest.

- Before starting the vm, enable audio in the vm's audio settings.
- In the windows guest, [install the virtualbox guest additions](http://www.geekyprojects.com/tutorials/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-a-windows-7-vm/) to get the soundcard driver. Alternatively you can [install it directly](http://en.gpunktschmitz.de/182-getting-sound-working-in-virtualbox-guest-windows-7-no-audio-output-device-is-installed)

If it doesn't work, try the workaround in this question:
"[How can I get my microphone to work in a virtualbox windows xp guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4751/how-can-i-get-my-microphone-to-work-in-a-virtualbox-windows-xp-guest)"

Good luck !